# How to override the right task in sbt plugin ?

Tags: scala, sbt

Someone could explain to me what is the `scope` and `configuration` of a given `task` when they are used without specifying ?

```
> show libraryDependencies
[info] * org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.12

> show {.}/ *:libraryDependencies
[info] *

> show {.}/libraryDependencies
[info] *

> show */ *:libraryDependencies
[info] *

> show *:libraryDependencies
[info] * org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.12
```

It seems that `*:libraryDependencies` equals to `libraryDependencies`. Is that correct ?

So in the plugin code, you need to override `projectSettings` , not `globalSettings` or `buildSettings`, correct ?

And then you do not use any of the `Configuration`, meaning nothing in the `.in()` call, correct ?

Answer (score 0):

This is well explained in the official documentation now. What you're looking for are rules for [scope delegation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scope-Delegation.html), which are basically how SBT resolves task and settings when you refer to them, but they are not defined with that particular axis configuration.

In short, when you write just `someKey`, it is interpreted as `<current project> / <key-dependent configuration> / Zero / someKey`, meaning that it is scoped to the current project in your shell, configuration which depends on the key itself, and `Zero` task scope. If no value is assigned to the key in this particular scope, then scope delegation is used to find a definition, if it is at all present.

Note that the `task.in(something)` syntax is a legacy of 0.13 and earlier versions of SBT, and is no longer recommended to be used. Use the unified slash syntax - all examples in documentation use it, and it is usually easier to read and understand than the old syntax.